# Tracking Elapsed Time with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, storage

So I a countdown timer for a task, and I want to know if there is a way to store the time that has elapsed so that it can be recorded in the app. So for example evertyime you used the countdown timer you would store the time that the countdown was running as a lifetime value.

- Countdown timer set for 10 minutes
- Timer runs for 5 minutes and 30 seconds, with 4 minutes and 30
  seconds remaining on the timer.
- The value of the elapsed session time (5 minutes and 30 seconds) is stored
  in the app and added to a total

If this exact set of instructions was repeated the total lifetime value would be 11 minutes.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a resource that would explain how to implement such functionality this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want this to persist across app launches?

Comment: You should take into account whether your "logical time" elapses when user backgrounds/kills the app/turns off the device. Be careful with timers as they *do not guarantee* the amount of time which elapses. Also the user can tinker with device time settings.

Comment: Hi brandonscript, yes I would like this to persist across app launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options available to you for persisting a number like that - the absolute easiest and quickest is probably just to use `UserDefaults` to store/retrieve the number.  That is not exactly the intended use for `UserDefaults`, but if you're just storing one `TimeInterval` it's not going to cause you any problems.

A bare bones implementation would look like this:

```
 let interval: TimeInterval = 20 //replace with the time from your countdown timer
 UserDefaults.standard.set(interval, forKey: "totalTimeElapsed")
```

And since you need to add the new time to the existing elapsed time, you would do something like this:

```
 let newTimeElapsed: TimeInterval = 20 //replace with time from countdown timer
 let totalSoFar = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "totalTimeElapsed") //will be 0 if it doesn't exist
 UserDefaults.standard.set(newTimeElapsed + totalSoFar, forKey: "totalTimeElapsed")
```

Other standard ways you could do this would be `NSKeyedArchiver` or `Core Data`, though `Core Data` would be major overkill for persisting 1 number.

Comment: Well it wouldn't just be a single instance this would continue to occur for all future instances of the app. And what if the user doesn't complete the countdown? I don't want to to store the timer total, only the time actually spent completing a task

Comment: @Trlewi Yes, that will persist across launches of the app. You will need to determine how much time has elapsed at the time the timer is stopped, and use that number in place of `newTimeElapsed` in my example. That was just a placeholder. As you can see, in my example I set the new value to be the previous total + the new time each time.